# Visual Basics: Assume that m is an **integer** variable that has been given a value. Write a statement that assign to the **string** variable

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Visual Basics: Assume that m is an **integer** variable  that has been given a value. Write a statement that assign to the **string** variable  s the formatted string corresponding to the value of m with two digits to the right of the decimial point and thousands separators.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: You seem to have mistaken us for your pupils.  I assure you, you're not our teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Format(CStr(m),"#,##0.00")
```